# How to get a list of files Google Drive API IOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, mime-types, google-drive-api

I am trying to integrate Google Drive Api for IOS. I am testing their example program [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/objectivec)

DrEdit when they upload or download a file they use mimetype such as when they upload a file

```
[GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:fileContent MIMEType:@"text/plain"];
```

when api downloads the same file it uses

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList]; query.q = @"mimeType = 'text/plain'";
```

I can upload and download files made in `Dr.Edit` but if I modify or create a file using web interface or using local drive client for `mac os`. These file are not shown in my application. I tried different mimeTypes, and different search parameters from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters). But it works only for files created in `Dr.Edit`. What is the problem?

Is there any other parameters which can help me display all files in `Google Drive`.

Comment: maybe you have the wrong scope: https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes

Comment: yes, you are right. I have changed in (IBAction)authButtonClicked  [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope: from kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile to kGTLAuthScopeDrive and it works well. There are constants in GTLDriveConstats.m // Authorization scope
NSString * const kGTLAuthScopeDrive                 = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
NSString * const kGTLAuthScopeDriveAppsReadonly     = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly";
NSString * const kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile             = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file";
and others. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changed the scope in method `authButtonClicked` of `DrEditFilesListViewController.m`

Replace this scope  `kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile` with `kGTLAuthScopeDrive` as follow

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController = 
  [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:**kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile**
                                             clientID:kClientId
                                         clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                     keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                             delegate:self
                                     finishedSelector:finishedSelector];
```

to

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController = 
  [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:**kGTLAuthScopeDrive**
                                             clientID:kClientId
                                         clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                     keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                             delegate:self
                                     finishedSelector:finishedSelector];
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable.

Comment: Failed to get the files in google drive
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426076/failed-to-get-the-files-from-google-drive-in-ios