# Failed to get the files from Google Drive in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-drive-api

Here is my code .

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
query.q = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@' IN parents", @"root"];
[self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,GTLDriveFileList *files, NSError *error)
{
    if (error == nil) {
        if (self.driveFiles == nil) {
            self.driveFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [self.driveFiles removeAllObjects];
        [self.driveFiles addObjectsFromArray:files.items];
        [tbDownload reloadData];
    } 
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

I'm getting the error by using this code .

n error occurred: `Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Login Required)" UserInfo=0x8f72a40 {error=Login Required, GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x8f647a0: {message:"Login Required" code:401 data:[1]}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Login Required)}`

I Already login with google drive in my app .

Comment: My guess is you're not setting the OAuth token correctly (or at all) in your GTLQueryDrive (shared?) instance.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to set OAuth Token , so that i will check in my code whether it is correct or wrong

Comment: No idea - you haven't shown that code at all. Check the docs for the library you're using?

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't configuring your `GTLServiceDrive` with the `GTMOAuth2Authentication` instance you get after successful authentication.

Example code:

```
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)authResult error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error) {
        // Auth failed, handle the error
    }
    else {
        self.driveService.authorizer = authResult;
    }
}
```